# Delayed $watch by using $timeout

Tags: angularjs

I have a Typehead text box as 'Model.Property'.So I need to delayed the ajax call to the server when user types.I have used below code snippet for that.But still it executes number of characters which have been typed.How can I avoid it ?

**JS**

```
  $scope.$watch('Model.Property', function () {

                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.MyFunction();
                }, 5000);

        });
```

**HTML**

```
<div pr-form-input name="MyReson" model="Model.Property" isrequired="true"></div>
```

Comment: This won't work because you still sending multiple calls with multiple inputs, how about making the $watch work when the element get blured out?

Comment: @BenDiamant Sorry I didn't get you ? I need to watch the the textbox value and if user types something then need to go to the server and brings the json result.But I need it to done after above time delay.

Comment: Yes but let say your using is typing "Test", you will send the request with "T", "Te", "Tes", "Test" regard the timeout

Comment: @BenDiamant Yes.That is the exact problem now I'm having.So how can I avoid it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the html element for Model.Property and I'll show you

Comment: You could cancel the timeout.
`if ($scope.timeout) { $scope.timeout.cancel(); }
$scope.timeout = $timeout(...);`

Comment: @BenDiamant Done that.Actually this is a custom directive.But it's a text box.

Comment: @AndreasArgelius Can you put it as a solution with bit more explanation.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is the update the server for change when the itme is blured out:

Your HTML tag:

```
<div pr-form-input name="Cause" ng-change="updateServer()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" model="Model.Property" isrequired="true"></div>
```

Inside your controller:

```
$scope.updateServer = function() {
    MyServerService.update($scope.Model.Property)
}
```

Explaination:

> **ng-change** - directive to trigger a function upon model change
>
> **ng-model-options** - directive to configure model-observation changes (configured to on-blur)

For Ajs **1.2.X** users : **[ngModelOptions for AngularJS 1.2](https://github.com/fergaldoyle/modelOptions)**

Comment: Ok.I'm going to implement it.Is that mean I don't need to use $watch ? I'm using AJs 1.2.5 Is that ok ?

Comment: @Sampath hoo no - ngModelOptions was introduced only in Angular 1.3.x. If you want to use similar functionality in Angular 1.2.x, check out this poly fill:

https://github.com/fergaldoyle/modelOptions